# idempotent functor

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Suppose we have $inc:C \rightarrow D$ a full subcategory and an adjunction $F:D\leftrightarrow C: inc$ where

1. $C$ and $D$ are complete and cocomplete categories.
2. $F$ is a left adjoint such that $F\circ F=F$
3. $inc$ commutes with colimits.

Does $F$ commute with finite limits in general and with pullback and product in particular?

Comment: Consider the full inclusion of sets into directed graphs (aka quivers) given by taking the discrete graph on a set. This functor $\Delta$ is full and faithful, hence exhibits Set as a full subcategory of Graph. It has a right adjoint given by the forgetful functor $\hom(1, -): \text{Graph} \to \text{Set}$, and a left adjoint $\pi_0$ which assigns to a graph its set of connected components. This $\pi_0$ does not preserve pullbacks.

Comment: @ToddTrimble As far as I understand $\pi_{0}$  preserves products, right ? is it a general fact that $F$ in my question has to preserve the product ?

Comment: What does $F \circ F = F$ mean? Anyway, I think the question is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243514

Comment: It's clear that "$F \circ F = F$" isn't literally correct; rather, the counit $F \circ i \to 1$ is an isomorphism since $i$ is full and faithful, and it follows that $F i F \cong F$ (or that we have an idempotent monad, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $F$ preserves neither pullbacks nor even products. In a comment I mentioned that the "discrete graph" functor $\text{Set} \to \text{Set}^{\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet}$ is full and faithful and has a left adjoint $\pi_0$ which sends a graph to its set of connected components and a right adjoint which sends a graph to its set of vertices. The functor $F = \pi_0$ preserves neither finite products nor equalizers. For products, consider the product of two copies of $0 \to 1$, which has four vertices but only one edge. For equalizers, consider the equalizer of an obvious pair of maps from $0 \to 1 \to 2$ to the "diamond" consisting of edges $S \to W \to N$ and $S \to E \to N$; the equalizing object is the discrete graph on vertices $0, 2$).

(In an earlier version of this answer, I had mistakenly said that $\pi_0$ preserves products, but I was conflating the case of (directed) graphs = quivers with the case of *reflexive graphs*, where the $\pi_0$ does preserve products.)

Similarly, let $\text{Set}^\mathbb{Z}$ denote the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-sets, i.e., sets equipped with an automorphism. The functor $\text{Set} \to \text{Set}^\mathbb{Z}$ which assigns to a set $S$ the trivial $\mathbb{Z}$-action is full and faithful, and has a right adjoint which assigns to a $\mathbb{Z}$-set $X$ its set of fixed points $X^\mathbb{Z} = \hom(1, X)$ under the action, and a left adjoint which assigns to $X$ its set of orbits = connected components $\pi_0(X) = X \otimes_\mathbb{Z} 1$. The functor $\pi_0$ does not preserve products, as we easily see looking at $X = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$: here $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ has infinitely many orbits under the action by the automorphism $(m, n) \mapsto (m+1, n+1)$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ has only one.

In general, we *can* say that $F$ preserves the terminal object: if $1$ denotes the terminal in $D$, then we have a unit map $1 \to i F 1$ which in fact is an isomorphism (because any algebra for an idempotent monad such as $i F$ has this property). In that case, for any object $c$ of $C$ there is a unique map $i c \to i F 1$, but then by full faithfulness of $i$, there is a unique map $c \to F 1$.

Comment: This result in the last paragraph is quite interesting and sort of unexpected. Any functor with a fully faithful right adjoint preserves the terminal object. Is there any high-level explanation why this should be true? In your proof, $1$ probably denotes a terminal in $D$. And that $1 \to iF1$ is an isomorphism is simply because it is inverse to the unique map $iF1 \to 1$.

Comment: @HeinrichD Thanks; I got the $C$ and $D$ mixed up (fixed now). I'm not sure I have anything high-level to add, except for my parenthetical remark on algebras of idempotent monads (they are characterized by a *property*, that the unit is an isomorphism). The high-level explanation might reside within the general yoga of stuff, structure, and property (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property), where idempotent monads govern property-like structure due to full faithfulness of $i$. Then combine that with the general observation that the terminal object is an algebra of any monad.

Comment: Here is an intuitive way of putting it: think of your typical idempotent monad as being a "completion monad"; examples include the field of fractions monad on integral domains, or the Cauchy completion of metric spaces, or the Stone-Cech compactification of Tychonoff spaces. (In each of these cases, the unit *embeds* an object into its completion, so this wouldn't apply to the abelianization monad on groups. Never mind that for now.) Thus $F$ is a completion functor; an algebra of the completion monad is something already complete, so $F$ doesn't "add anything". Then observe $1$ is complete.